# Изменить class дива из JS

Tags: bootstrap, html5, javascript

В Bootstrap 3 я объявляю div таким образом, к примеру:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col"></div>
```

Из javascript можно как-то изменить количество колонок на 12, то есть на `col-lg-12`?

Хочу, чтобы див по нажатию на кнопку растянулся на весь экран, а остальные столбцы спрятать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, если на странице один элемент с таким классом, то приведенный код можно оставить и так, но если их много и надо изменить один, то надо придумать как выбрать конкретный. Само изменение делается довольно просто:

```
//Javascript
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("col-lg-4")[0]
a.classList.remove("col-lg-4");
a.classList.add("col-lg-12");
```

или

```
//Jquery
$(".col-lg-4").removeClass("col-lg-4").addClass("col-lg-12")
```